# CakePHP display all data between 2 dates

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am new for CakePHP.
Now I'm having a task which is **self-learning** where I want to display all the data from PhpMyAdmin between **2 selected dates** when user **click 'Show'** and display at the **same page** which is *"index.ctp"*.

However, I'm stuck where I do now know where should I put the codes that can display all the information.
Below are the codes I had done till now:

---

Model (room.php):

```
<?php
class Room extends AppModel{
    public  $validate = array( 
        'sdate' => array(
            'date' => array(
                //Add 'ymd' to the rule.
                'rule' => array('date', 'ymd'),
                'message' => 'Please select a valid start date.',
            ),
        ),
    );
        'edate' => array(
            'date' => array(
                //Add 'ymd' to the rule.
                'rule' => array('date', 'ymd'),
                'message' => 'Please select a valid end date.',
            ),
        ),
    );
}
```

---

Controller (RoomController.php):

```
    <?php
    class RoomsController extends AppController{
        public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');
        public $components = array('Session');

        public function index() {

        }

    }
?>
```

---

index.ctp

```
    <h1>Room Reservation<h1>

<table>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->create('rooms', 
            array(
                'type' => 'get'
            )
        );
        echo $this->Form->input('Start Date:',
            array(
                'label' => 'Start Date', 
                'id' => 'sdate'
            )
        );
        echo $this->Form->input('End Date:',
            array(
                'label' => 'End Date', 
                'id' => 'edate'
            )
        );
        echo $this->Form->end('Show');
    ?>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#sdate').Zebra_DatePicker();
        $('#edate').Zebra_DatePicker();
    });
</script>
```

---

room_type(Database):

```
CREATE TABLE `room_type` (
`room_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`room_type` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`no_of_room` int(10) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`room_id`)
);

room_id | room_type | no_of_room
    1   |     A     |    10
    2   |     B     |    10
    3   |     C     |    10
    4   |     D     |    10
```

---

room_type_availability(Database):

```
CREATE TABLE `room_type_availability` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`room_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`trx_date` date NOT NULL,
`no_of_room` int(2) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD KEY `room_id` (`room_id`),
CONSTRAINT `room_type_availability_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`room_id`) REFERENCES `room_type` (`room_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

    id | room_id | trx_date  | no_of_room
    1  |     1   |2015-05-05 |    10
    2  |     1   |2015-05-06 |    10
    3  |     1   |2015-05-07 |    9
    4  |     1   |2015-05-08 |    7
    5  |     1   |2015-05-09 |    6
    6  |     2   |2015-05-05 |    8
    7  |     2   |2015-05-06 |    3
    8  |     2   |2015-05-07 |    6
    9  |     2   |2015-05-08 |    4
   10  |     2   |2015-05-09 |    5
```

---

If the **date selected** are **in** the **database**, it will display the **room_type_availability database**.

Else if the **date selected** are **not** in **database**, it will display the **room_type database**.

Hope you guys can give some advice on it.

Thanks for helping and appreciate it.

:)

Answer (score 0):

```
//in controller

public function index() {

    if($this->request->isPost()) {
        $obj = $this->loadModel('RoomTypeAvailability');
        $start_date = $this->request->data['sdate'];
        $end_date  = $this->request->data['edate'];
        // use this "between" range
        $conditions = array('RoomTypeAvailability.trx_date BETWEEN ? and ?' => array($start_date, $end_date));
        $data = $this->RoomTypeAvailability->find('all',array('conditions'=>$conditions)); 
        $this->set('data', $data);
    }  
}
```

in Room Model

```
class Room extends AppModel{

public $useTable = false;

public  $validate = array( 
    'sdate' => array(
        'date' => array(
            //Add 'ymd' to the rule.
            'rule' => array('date', 'ymd'),
            'message' => 'Please select a valid start date.',
        ),
    ),
);
    'edate' => array(
        'date' => array(
            //Add 'ymd' to the rule.
            'rule' => array('date', 'ymd'),
            'message' => 'Please select a valid end date.',
        ),
    ),
);
}
```

in RoomType Model

```
class RoomTypeAvailability extends AppModel {

    public $useTable = 'room_type_availability';

    public $validate = array( );
}
```

// index.ctp

```
<h1>Room Reservation<h1>

<table>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->create('rooms', 
            array(
                'type' => 'post'
            )
        );
        echo $this->Form->input('Start Date:',
            array(
                'label' => 'Start Date', 
                'id' => 'sdate',
                'name' => 'sdate'
            )
        );
        echo $this->Form->input('End Date:',
            array(
                'label' => 'End Date', 
                'id' => 'edate',
                'name' => 'edate'
            )
        );
        echo $this->Form->end('Show');
    ?>
</table>
<?php if(isset($data) && count($data)>0) { ?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>room_type</th>
        <th>trx_date</th>
        <th>no_of_date</th>
    </tr>

    <?php foreach($data as $row) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['RoomTypeAvailability']['id']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['RoomTypeAvailability']['room_type']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['RoomTypeAvailability']['trx_date']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['RoomTypeAvailability']['no_of_date']?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>

</table>
<?php } ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#sdate').Zebra_DatePicker();
        $('#edate').Zebra_DatePicker();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: i got this problem 

Error: Call to undefined method RoomsController::find()

btw, thanks for helping :)

Comment: thanks for helping but it does not show the table out
where the sdate and edate at the controller it shows Undefined index :(

Comment: i think something you missed. its working properly in my system. set hard code for `sdate` and `edate` just for testing.

Comment: i had followed what u gave~
it is database problem or date problem?

in database i had define the room_type as FK~

Comment: i had update at the question there


room_type and room_type_availability

Comment: @SavageL, your schema design is wrong, you can't define room_type as primary key, its data type no support in mysql.

Comment: i had changed the PK to room_id.
but I need the room_type to display out how should I call it?

Comment: Error : **Key column 'room_id' doesn't exist in table**

Comment: i had updated the latest database code above
sorry ><